# Pass value to parameter of a function called inside a JQuery onClick event and evaluate it correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I came across this bizarre behaviour while trying to assign a value to a parameter of a function that is then reused inside onClick event and in other parts of my code.

I have a function `fctClearAllInputs` that clears values from input and has to show a confirmation popup depending on where it's called from.

When `fctClearAllInputs(true)` is called inside `$("#idBtnCallClearFunction")` onClick event, the parameter `blnClearWithoutConfirmation` is evaluated to true correctly.

However, when `fctClearAllInputs` is called inside `$(".clearAllInputs")` onClick event, its parameter `blnClearWithoutConfirmation` is an object and is not properly evaluated (an object value is truthy in JS: `!!{} == true`).

Setting a default value for `blnClearWithoutConfirmation` to `false` is ignored

If I change `fctClearAllInputs` to `fctClearAllInputs(false)` inside `$(".clearAllInputs")`, then the parameter `blnClearWithoutConfirmation` is correctly set to `false`, but the buttons with class `clearAllInputs` are not clickable anymore.

What is this behaviour and how can I pass a value to a parameter of a function called inside a JQuery event and **evaluated it correctly** inside my function ?

---

See code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const fctClearAllInputs = function (blnClearWithoutConfirmation = false) {
    console.log(`blnClearWithoutConfirmation: '${JSON.stringify(blnClearWithoutConfirmation)}'`);
    console.log(`Convert to bool: '${!!blnClearWithoutConfirmation}'`);

    //blnClearWithoutConfirmation inside 'fctClearAllInputs(false)' is true but button will not be clickable

    //blnClearWithoutConfirmation inside 'fctClearAllInputs' is an object evaluated to true but button will be clickable

    //...

    // blnClearWithoutConfirmation==true => clear inputs without confirmation popup
    if (!!blnClearWithoutConfirmation) {
      // clear inputs
    }
    // blnClearWithoutConfirmation==false => show confirmation popup then clear if user accepts
    else {
      // show popup
      // clear inputs
    }
  };

  // set onclick event to all buttons with class 'clearAllInputs'
  $(".clearAllInputs").on("click", fctClearAllInputs); //fctClearAllInputs(false)

  // button to call clear function and also do other things
  $("#idBtnCallClearFunction").on("click", function() {
    // DO THINGS

    fctClearAllInputs(true);

    // DO OTHER THINGS
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<button class="clearAllInputs">Clear All Inputs #1</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="clearAllInputs">Clear All Inputs #2</button>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<button id="idBtnCallClearFunction">
  Call Clear Function
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery passes the `Event` object as the argument when it calls the function directly, so the default won't be used. You should use your own anonymous function like you do in the other handler.

```js
// set onclick event to all buttons with class 'clearAllInputs'
$(".clearAllInputs").on("click", function() {
  fctClearAllInputs.bind(this)()
}); //fctClearAllInputs(false)

// button to call clear function and also do other things
$("#idBtnCallClearFunction").on("click", function() {
  // DO THINGS

  fctClearAllInputs.bind(this)(true);

  // DO OTHER THINGS
});
```

Comment: yes, works as expected. Didn't know I had to call it this way.

Comment: I hit another roadblock. My buttons contains data attributes `<button class="clearAllInputs" data-value="..."></button>` and my function is using those data attributes. However, if I use a lambda function, those data attributes are evaluated as `undefined` and here's how I assign them: `const strValue = $(this).data("value");`. Any idea on how to get the data attributes inside the lambda function ?

Comment: The problem is that `this` isn't passed when you do it like you wrote. I've updated the answer to show how to pass on `this`.